# gpg does not know options --output --armor

Tags: gnupg

I wanted to export my secret files, but gpg seem not to know the options `--armor` and `--output`:

```
$ gpg --export XXX --armor --output temp/key.asc
gpg: Note: '--armor' is not considered an option
gpg: Note: '--output' is not considered an option
```

gpg version is 2.2.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the order of the arguments. You can use the one letter version of the option, this should work:

```
gpg -a -o temp/key.asc --export XXX
```

Comment: thanks, order of arguments which are not positional arguments, great...

Answer (score 0):

From the gpg manage:

```
gpg [ --homedir dir ] [ --options file ] [ options ] command [ args ]
```

Options must come before the command.

And `--export` is, according to the manpage, a command; specifically it's in the category of "Commands to select the type of operation"

So, the way gpg parses the cmd line arguments is that once it finds a command, everything after that is treated as the [ args ] from up above, presumably as arguments for the command (in this case as args for the --export command)